# On the Topological Properties of a Solution Set of Equations

Tags: general-topology, analysis

The following is from some qualifying exam.

Let $f(x,y,z)=2x^{2}-2xy+5y^{2}+z^{4}-6$ and $g(x,y,z)=xyz-1$, is the set
\begin{align*}
S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}:f(x,y,z)=g(x,y,z)=0\}
\end{align*}
closed, compact, connected?

To tackle this problem, I let $h(x,y,z)=f(x,y,z)-g(x,y,z)$, then $S=h^{-1}(\{0\})\cap g^{-1}(\{0\})$. While both $h$ and $g$ are continuous, so $S$ is closed.

But I cannot determine if $S$ is compact or connected. For the compactness, one may try to determine if $S$ is a bounded set, but how?

Comment: Hints: Look at the zero sets of $f$ and $g$ separately for boundedness. For connectedness, note that the zero set of $g$ does not touch any coordinate plane; can you show there are solutions of the form $(x, y, z)$ and $(-x, -y, z)$?

Comment: But even both zero sets of $f$ and $g$ are unbounded, how do you claim that their intersection must be unbounded as well?

Comment: How do you know they're both unbounded...? :)

Comment: Actually I feel like the zero set of $f$ is actually bounded, but failing to prove that, any further hint for this?

Answer (score 1):

For any fixed $z$ the zero set of $f$ is an ellipse, and if $|z| > 6^{\frac14}$ there are no solutions, so the zero set of $f$ is bounded, and so is $S,$ therefore. The zero set of a continuous function (or a set of such) is closed, so $S$ is closed and bounded. The zero set of $f$ is centrally symmetric, since $f(-x, -y, -z) = f(x, y, z),$ so from the comment you can deduce that $S$ is not connected.

Comment: The zero set of $f$ is not connected, and neither is the $g$, but right now it is the intersection, so the result is also not connected?

Comment: @user284331 The zero set of $f$ *is* connected, but the intersection does not appear to be.